I am getting the answer as 4, so where am I making the mistake?
Question: In an examination, the average marks of 4 girls and 6 boys is 24. Each of the girls has the same marks while each of the boys has the same marks. If the marks of any girl is at most double the marks of any boy, but not less than the marks of any boy, then the number of possible distinct integer values of the total marks of 2 girls and 6 boys is
$$(a)19\qquad(b)21\qquad    (c)20\qquad    (d)22$$
Link of the question: https://online.2iim.com/CAT-question-paper/CAT-2023-Question-Paper-Slot-1-Quant/quants-question-10.shtml
My Ans:  $$4G+6B=240$$
$$2G+3B=120$$
Now, $$B\le G\le2B$$
$$B\le\frac{120-3B}2\le2B$$
On solving: $B\in\{18,19,20,21,22,23,24\}$
If I calculate $G$ using $2G+3B=120$ then $B\in\{18,20,22,24\}$ will give me distinct values of $2G+6B$
=> 4 integral values. So where am I making the mistake?

Just as a guess:  the problem does not state that $B,G$ are integers.  It simply requires that $2G+6B$ be an integer.  To the extent that $B,G$ represent averages, it seems reasonable to allow rational values for them.

@lulu: Looking at the answer in the link, it seems that you are right. What a dreadful question! Normally I would say that exam marks can be assumed to be integers. When they are not, as here, it should be clearly stated.

@TonyK  I agree, with the one caveat that I mentioned:  if we are to regard $B,G$ as averages themselves (which I think we are, but it sure isn't clear) then rational values are to be expected.  But, yeah.  The phrasing is just awful.

Should say:  until @TonyK pointed it out, I hadn't realized that the link contained the full solution (hadn't even opened the link).  Given that the solution, presumably, is equivalent to the one I wrote out, perhaps I should delete my posted solution?  Well, I'll leave it up for now anyway.

The problem does not require that $B,G$ be integers, only that $2G+6B$ be an integer.
Note that $B=G\implies B=G=24$ and that $G=2B\implies B=\frac G2=\frac {120}7$.
The two extreme cases give us $$192≥2G+6B≥\left \lceil \frac {1200}7\right \rceil=172$$  As there are exactly $21$ distinct integers in that range, the answer is $(b)$.
Note:  as discussed in the comments, the phrasing of the problem is quite poor.  If, as the OP did, we assume that marks on an exam are integers, then you get the result the OP obtained.  I think (guess?) that we are meant to interpret $G,B$ as averages (that's why all the girls have the same score, and all the boys.  If that's the case, then rational values make sense.  But, really, the phrasing should be improved.  We shouldn't have to make guesses of this type.
